# Erlang - Random Number Generator

Tags: random, erlang, integer

I am using the following to generate a near random number.

```
3> erlang:ref_to_list(make_ref()).

"#Ref<0.0.0.36>"
```

What I want is 00036

Well it was what I had been informed I could do in a previous post. It occurred to me that it is not so easy to extract the numbers from make ref.

Can anyone show how it is easily done, or possibly recommend another solution.

Keep in mind that using random:seed() is not random when called within the same few nano seconds.

Regards

Comment: Don't re-seed your random number generator every time it's called. Seed once then use it. The `random` module is perfectly fine for this.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want random numbers or unique numbers? They're very different creatures and 'make_ref' in _no way_ produces random numbers.

Comment: Yeah, and add for what you want to use the random numbers, is it game, simulation or security.  Because for security you want totally differen random numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Note: from OTP 18* `erlang:now/0` *and* `random` *module are deprecated, and OTP 20 will remove the* `random` *module.* See [Time and Time Correction in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html) for the further details. Also, you no longer need to do the per-process seeding if you use `rand:uniform/0`. The following is left as is for reference.

---

The problem is that you are using `random` incorrectly. `random:seed/0` will seed the random number generator with the very same seed always. This is not good for what you want. Rather, you can use `random:seed(erlang:now())` to seed it with another number, namely the current time.

"What happens if two calls come very close?" you may ask. Well, the Erlang guys thought about this, so `now/0` is guaranteed to always return increasing numbers:

> Returns  the  tuple  {MegaSecs,  Secs,  MicroSecs}  which is the
>                elapsed time since 00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970 (zero hour) on the
>                assumption that the underlying OS supports this. Otherwise, some
>                other point in time is chosen. **It is also guaranteed that subse‐
>                quent  calls to this BIF returns continuously increasing values.**
>                Hence, the return value from  now()  can  be  used  to  generate
>                unique  time-stamps,  and  if  it is called in a tight loop on a
>                fast machine the time of the node can become skewed.

(emphasis mine)

Also note that the `random` PRNG is per-process, so you should always start your process up with a seeder call:

```
init([..]) ->
  random:seed(erlang:now()),
  [..]
  {ok, #state { [..] }}.
```

---

Using references for this is perhaps possible, but I don't think it is a viable one. The solution goes over `erlang:ref_to_list/1` and it is not pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting point about now().  I was timing my app and getting 1 microsecond, with what you said it means my time could be even faster!  Either way could you write an edit with the way you would do it?

Comment: You still have not said if you want a value that is unique (no one else has the value) or random (no one can easily guess the value). Further, you have not stated to which extent the randomness is needed. You may want to elaborate on those things - otherwise people can't help you.

Comment: +1 for the "PRNG is per-process". This was actually the information I was looking for.

Comment: For more random & secure seeds, you should use `crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1`.

Comment: For OTP 18 and later, simply use `rand:uniform/0`. It automates seeding which uses not only time-dependent values but also all the other monotonically-increasing number generators. And remember `erlang:now/0` has been deprecated. See http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html for the further details.

Comment: @jj1bdx so no need to use any seeding in OTP 18+?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly perform seeding on Erlang rand module. See https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint-25/lib/stdlib/src/rand.erl#L280-L283 for how the default seeding of the rand module is done on OTP 25.