# How to generate a random alphanumeric string with Erlang?

Tags: string, utf-8, erlang

I'm trying to generate an random alphanumeric ID with Erlang.
I naively tried `crypto:strong_rand_bytes(Bytes)` to generate a random binary and then used that binary like it was created with `<<"my_unique_random_id">>` - which didn't work because random bits are not necessarily a valid UTF-8 string, right?

Well, I looked for other options in the erlang docs and elsewhere, but I didn't find anything. Could someone point me to a solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might depend on the randomness you need. Erlang's `crypto` module produces stronger random data than the `random` module (see also [[erlang-questions] Yaws security alert - Yaws 1.93](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-June/067566.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318156/how-to-create-a-list-of-1000-random-number-in-erlang/10319823#10319823)). If you want to use `strong_rand_bytes` to generate an ID maybe getting the base64 of it might be enough:

```
> base64:encode(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(Bytes)).
```

You could turn this into a list if needed.

Comment: This works for generating a random bitstring but does not create an alphanumeric string. The string may contain special characters like `+` and `=`.

Comment: Regex to the rescue: `re:replace(base64:encode(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(Bytes)),"\\W","",[global,{return,binary}]).`

Comment: Berzemus, the encoding of "[global,{retu‌​rn,binary}]" is non-ascii. It does not compile.  Those chars == "5b 67 6c 6f 62 61 6c 2c 7b 72 65 74 75 e2 80 8c e2 80 8b 72 6e 2c 62 69 6e 61 72 79 7d 5d" but [global, {return, binary}] in ascii should equal "5b 67 6c 6f 62 61 6c 2c 20 7b 72 65 74 75 72 6e 2c 20 62 69 6e 61 72 79 7d 5d". Also that \\W is not correctly encoded.

Answer (score 13):

According to [Generating random strings in Erlang](http://blog.teemu.im/2009/11/07/generating-random-strings-in-erlang/) it only takes a few lines of Erlang to generate a string of a specified length from a certain set of characters.

```
get_random_string(Length, AllowedChars) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(_, Acc) ->
                        [lists:nth(random:uniform(length(AllowedChars)),
                                   AllowedChars)]
                            ++ Acc
                end, [], lists:seq(1, Length)).
```

The blog post has a line-by-line explanation of the code.  Look to the comments for a couple of optimization tips.

Comment: To have different results every time you restart your Erlang VM you should seed the randomizer, (example: `random:seed(erlang:now())`). 
For more info take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4975193/727663) or [here](http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-erlang/)

Comment: It's better to use `crypto:rand_uniform(1, length(AllowedChars))`

Comment: Your link is dead. Try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161017094433/http://blog.teemu.im/2009/11/07/generating-random-strings-in-erlang/) cached result.

Answer (score 6):

I have prepared small module do to this
Also it uses `crypto:rand_uniform/2` but not obsolete `random:uniform`

```
module(cloud_rnd).

-export([rnd_chars/1, rnd_numbers/1, rnd_chars_numbers/1]).

rnd_chars(L)         -> get_rnd(L, chars).
rnd_numbers(L)       -> get_rnd(L, numbers).
rnd_chars_numbers(L) -> get_rnd(L, chars_numbers).

get_rnd(L, chars)         -> gen_rnd(L, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
get_rnd(L, numbers)       -> gen_rnd(L, "1234567890");
get_rnd(L, chars_numbers) -> gen_rnd(L, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890").

gen_rnd(Length, AllowedChars) ->
  MaxLength = length(AllowedChars),
  lists:foldl(
    fun(_, Acc) -> [lists:nth(crypto:rand_uniform(1, MaxLength), AllowedChars)] ++ Acc end,
    [], lists:seq(1, Length)
  ).
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with responses to the various "I need random strings" questions (in whatever language) is almost every solution uses a flawed specification, namely, string length. The questions themselves rarely reveal why the random strings are needed, but I will boldly assume they are to be used as identifiers which need to be unique.

There are two leading ways to get strictly unique strings: deterministically (which is not random) and store/compare (which is onerous). What to do? Give up the ghost. Go with *probabilistic uniqueness* instead. That is, accept that there is some (however small) risk that your strings won't be unique. This is where understanding collision probability and entropy are helpful.

So I'll rephrase my bold assumption as you need some number of identifiers with a small risk of repeat. As a concrete example, let's say you need 5 million Ids with a less than 1 in a trillion risk of repeat. So what length of string do you need?  Well, that question is underspecified as it depends on the characters used. But more importantly, it's misguided. What you need is specification of the entropy of the strings, not their length.

This is where [EntropyString](https://github.com/EntropyString/Erlang) can help.

```
Bits = entropy_string:bits(5.0e6, 1.0e12).
83.37013046707142
entropy_string:random_string(Bits).
<<"QDrjGQFGgGjJ4t9r2">>
```

There are other predefined characters sets, and you can specify your own characters as well (though for efficiency reasons only sets with powers of 2 characters are supported). And best of all, the risk of repeat in the specified number of strings is explicit. No more guessing with string length.

Answer (score 1):

```
randchar(N) ->
   randchar(N, []).

randchar(0, Acc) ->
   Acc;
randchar(N, Acc) ->
   randchar(N - 1, [random:uniform(26) + 96 | Acc]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use function `uef_bin:random_latin_binary/2` from here:
https://github.com/DOBRO/uef-lib#uef_binrandom_latin_binary2

```
Bin = uef_bin:random_latin_binary(Length, any)
```

And then, if you need a `string()` type:

```
String = erlang:binary_to_list(Bin)
```